# Implementing Java interface in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a **Java** interface:

```
public interface NonHindiQuery {
    void onNonHindiQueryReceived(String Query);
}
```

I want to implement it on **Kotlin** class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {...}
```

**Q:** How can I do it?

Comment: add `, NonHindiQurary` after `AppCompatActivity()` before class body

Comment: now i getting this error   kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented

Comment: you must implement interface methods in your class, you've get this error because `MainActivity` must implement `void onNonHindiQuraryRecived(String Queary)`; or set your class as abstract. but you need first way

Comment: i implemented interface , then i get this error

Comment: this is how i did it class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NonHindiQurary

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's simple:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NonHindiQuery {
    override fun onNonHindiQueryReceived(q: String) {
        // <...>
    }
}
```

To get rid of [`kotlin.NotImplementedError`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-not-implemented-error/index.html#notimplementederror) remove `TODO("not implemented")` from the method body:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun TODO(reason: String): Nothing = 
    throw NotImplementedError("An operation is not implemented: $reason")
```

Comment: @Alexander Romanov could you help me on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45293506/1830228

Comment: What rubbish. why they do such stupid things :) BTW this worked. thanks