# Java Interface Objects in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Consider I have an interface like the one below:

```
interface JSONObjectRequestListener {
    fun onSuccess()
    fun onFailure()
}
```

Now I have a method in my MainActivity:

```
fun onRequestHappen(listener: JSONObjectRequestListener)
```

If this were java, I would have passed this object as:

```
onRequestHappen(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse() {
        // do anything with response
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

How do I pass this interface's object in Kotlin?

NB. Please don't mark this as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800502/implementing-java-interface-in-kotlin) as what that question requests is completely different from what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your listener like this:

```
val listener = object : JSONObjectRequestListener {

    override fun onResponse() {
        // do anything with response
    }

    override fun onError() {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

And pass it to your func like below:

```
onRequestHappen(listener)
```

To do this inside the func call you can use the following code snippet:

```
onRequestHappen(object : JSONObjectRequestListener {

        override fun onResponse() {
            // do anything with response
        }

        override fun onError() {
            // handle error
        }
    })
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it inside the function call?